# Query on Regular Expressions in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm trying my hand in learning Regular Expressions in Oracle ( rather, my first attempt in doing anything with RegEx).

What does the character `^` signify at the start ?
The documentation mentions

```
Use the caret and dollar sign to define patterns that match the start or end of a string.
^ defines that start of a string or column 1 of the string.
```

So by using `'^[*est]'` as the pattern, my understanding is that `match anything which has -est as its ending`.

However, when I tried it out,

```
SQL> select 1 from dual where regexp_like('test','^[*est]');

         1
----------
         1
```

---

```
SQL>  select 1 from dual where regexp_like('best','^[*est]');

no rows selected
```

---

```
SQL>  select 1 from dual where regexp_like('fest','^[*est]');

no rows selected
```

Removing the `^` however, and we get

```
SQL>  select 1 from dual where regexp_like('fest','[*est]');

         1
----------
         1
```

---

```
SQL>  select 1 from dual where regexp_like('best','[*est]');

         1
----------
         1
```

---

```
SQL> select 1 from dual where regexp_like('test','^[*est]');

         1
----------
         1
```

---

Why is this so ? Why is it that in the first case, the match happens for `test' but not for others ?

Comment: Good reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 1 from dual where regexp_like('best','^[*est]');
```

`[]` in regexps means "any of the listed characters"

Inside `[]`, the asterisk loses its special meaning and means just the asterisk.

The regexp above matches any string that begins with `*`, `e`, `s` or `t` (any of the listed characters following the beginning of the string).

To select words ending on `-est`, use this:

```
select 1 from dual where regexp_like('nest','est$')
```

which means "the string `est` followed by the end of string (`$`)"

Comment: So I take it then the first query meant, match any string which starts with `e`, `s`, `t`, `*` while the second query meant match any string which has `e`,`s`,`t`,`*` ?

Comment: The second query will match any string that ends on `est` (in that order). It will match `nest` and `best`, but not `nets` or `bets`.

Comment: Just to be clear clear, by second query I meant `regexp_like('fest','[*est]')` - You said `[]` in regexps means "any of the listed characters" - so I wanted to confirm that this means match any string which has `e`,`s`,`t`,`* ` .
Sorry if I caused any confusion

Comment: `@Sathya`: right. This one: `[*est]` means "any of the characters `*`, `e`, `s`, `t` anywhere in the string".

Answer (score 2):

Unless the regex syntax in Oracle is very different from all other regex implementations then you porbably want to change your `[]` to `()`. `[est]` matches either "e", "s" or "t". `(est)` on the other hand matches "est".